# ARKit: Placing Plane Between Two Nodes/Vectors

Tags: swift, arkit

I am trying to place a plane between two vectors. However, the direction of the plane matters as I am "pointing" arrows from the first node to the second node. This is what I have tried:

```
private func placeArrows(source: SCNVector3, destination: SCNVector3) {
    let height = source.distance(vector: destination)
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(0.4), height: CGFloat(height))
    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "Arrow")
    plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1,-height,1)
    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.wrapT = SCNWrapMode.repeat
    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.wrapS = SCNWrapMode.repeat

    let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    node.position = SCNVector3((source.x + destination.x) / 2, floor_pos_y, (source.z + destination.z) / 2)
    let dirVector = SCNVector3Make(destination.x - source.x, destination.y - source.y, destination.z - source.z)
    let yAngle = atan(dirVector.x / dirVector.z)
    node.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
    node.eulerAngles.y = yAngle
    route_nodes.append(node)
    ARView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
}
```

The planes end up pointing in both directions i.e. some toward the second node and some towards the first node. And I haven't been able to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit:**

[Here is a screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBrDc.jpg)

As you can see... one arrow is pointing to the left and one is pointing to the right. The desired result is for both arrows to be pointing in the same direction i.e. to the left

Comment: can u share output screenshot..

Comment: @PvDev I have added a screenshot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After trying to solve this issue at different angles, I finally found the issue.

```
let yAngle = atan(dirVector.x / dirVector.z)
```

This line should actually be replaced with the one below:

```
let yAngle = atan2(dirVector.x, dirVector.z)
```